# iOS: mail showing an old email only when the inbox is empty

Tags: ios, mail.app

When there is at least one email in my Exchange mailbox the mail app on iOS is working fine.

As soon as the inbox is empty, an old deleted message appears. If I delete it again, it reappears after less than one second.

As soon as I get a new message, the old deleted one is not shown anymore.

Removing the Exchange account and adding it again does not change the behaviour.

Any idea what I could try?